# web2py how to chain a grid on another action/view

Tags: web2py

I'd like to use the grid widget to explore a database, then proceed on another action/view that can compute on the selected rows

I currently export the grid result, upload it to the server, then manually launch a new action/view that reads the exported file.. which is a bit cumbersome

I have looked to the selectable attribute, it does allow to perform some actions on selected rows, but they must be selected manually, and the user will stay in the same grid view..

Any support for such a feature in web2py ?

Comment: Are you saying you want to be able to search the grid, and somehow record the query and/or set of records identified by the search, and then go to another action where that same set of records will be retrievable for further processing/display?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i meant..

Answer (score 1):

When you perform a search with `SQLFORM.grid`, a `keywords` parameter is added to the URL query string, which can be extracted in the controller via `request.vars.keywords`. Internally, the grid uses `SQLFORM.build_query(fields, keywords)` to convert the keywords to a DAL query. So, a strategy to re-construct the same query that the grid uses is to store the value of `request.vars.keywords` in the `session`, and later pass that value to `SQLFORM.build_query()`. For example:

```
def mygrid():
    session.grid_keywords = request.vars.keywords
    return dict(grid=SQLFORM.grid(db.mytable))

def other_action():
    dbset = db(db.mytable)
    if session.grid_keywords:
        dbset = dbset(SQLFORM.build_query(db.mytable, session.grid_keywords))
    records = dbset.select()
    return dict(records=records)
```

Then in the `mygrid` page, you can include a button/link to the `other_action` page, and the `records` selected there will match the records currently in the grid (note, the grid paginates, so it only shows a subset of records, but `records` in `other_action` above will select *all* matching records, with no pagination, which is presumably what you want).

Comment: Really great Anthony, that is exactly what i was searching for.. I have been able to launch the second action and reuse grid keywords. Now i am looking for the way to add a button to chain the second action, knowing that I would like to have a single button (I mean not one per row). Thank you very much

Comment: You can just add a button to the view of `mygrid`, which should link to `other_action`. For example: `<a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{=URL('other_action')}}">Other Action</a>`.